# White screen of death on admin and other dashboard pages

Tags: wp-admin, fatal-error

I have created a theme for the first time. but except the public area I cannot access admin by wp-admin. After changing he theme I saved redirected URL of admin which is this -->http://www.tennis-florida.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http://www.tennis-florida.com/wp-admin/&reauth=1, this takes me to login page and allows me to login then again none of the images are loading as they were previously mapped to localhost and now When I am trying to upload anything or add or modify post after licking submit button it gives me blank white page and I have to click back in order to get back to dashboard. So all in all the theme is completely useless. What I am trying to achieve is I have to ship this theme to client as they are already seen it and so I have to make it work.

As I said I have figured it out that the problem is with the theme(For the record I have created the theme by following a YouTube tutorial)

I am sharing all my codes

http://pastebin.com/LavB6vcT 
this contains all the links for files that I have created, As I have only 1 reputation so cannot add more than 2 links.

sidebar was not required so haven't added anything in there, sidebar.php is blank.

That's all the files I have created apart from folders for images and all.

I have tried adding

```
ini_set('display_errors', true) ;
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Even when I am trying to add a post and such with that another alternate admin link just after click publish wp shows blank page but the data is being added.
to config and file and removing spaces in wp-config still no luck.
Note: I cannot give up on theme as client has already seen this theme and I cannot provide another.